# MySQL Query Nearest Lowest Value & Actual Value Issue

Tags: mysql

I have table
'test' with fileds & values

```
id number
1   13
2   17
3   20
4   30
5   40
```

If i provide 14,15,16 then it should give me 13.
If i provide 22,24,24 then it should give me 20.
If i provide 13 then it should give me 13.
If i provide 20 then it should give me 20.

I'm looking for mysql query for this which provide nearest lowest value & actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you send a table with a list of values

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   MyTable
WHERE
   number <= (SELECT MIN(requireNuber) FROM InputTable)
ORDER BY 
   number DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Although, I'm sure you could only send the lowest value to MySQL from the client (why can't you) which would make the code look like

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   MyTable
WHERE
   number <= @MyParameter
ORDER BY 
   number DESC
LIMIT 1
```